# Polymer v.1 full screen paper-dialog

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm converting an old Stocks App from JQM to Polymer v.1 and i like to know if there is an easy way to have a dialog open at full screen. I checked the docs, maybe i missed something as i can see any ref to a full screen dialog.

The reason is when i click the plus button on the header to search and add a stock i get the dialog open ok

[image]

However when i search then the list populates but the dialog does not adjust on the page to fit/position accordingly

[image]

I have a workaround where i can append the list with blank paper items prior to opening the dialog

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
$("#stockslist").append('<paper-item></paper-item>');
}
```

[image]

But i would prefer if there is a class or correct css i could add to have the dialog open at full screen with no padding or margin

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did not test this, but you should be able to set the position and size on the dialog element. I have done something similar on a project I am working on.

```
paper-dialog { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;        
}
```